# How do I display posts from tagchildren of taxonomy tagparent

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Firstly, I'm trying to display all tags from a taxonomy called 'group'. However, this taxonomy currently contains two tags, from which one of of them has multiple tagchildren.

**Update: I should have mentioned it was for a particular post type.**

I'd lik to display all posts belonging to those children. So the final result should look something like this:

- Parent Tag A

  - Child tag

    - Post data
  - Child tag

    - Post data
  - etc...
- "Parent" Tag B

  ```
  <?php
  $taxonomyName = "group";
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
  foreach($terms as $term) {
          echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug,$taxonomyName).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
          $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
          echo '<ul>';
          foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
                  $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
                  echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
          }
          echo '</ul>';
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: what is the problem ???
You want to display all post containing `child tags` or `parent tags` ???

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar I'd like to display the posts that belong to a particular child tag. That's right.

Comment: I've done some research but I believe it's tricky and I'd be surprised if even the people here knew the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try this...

I hope this will work...

```
$taxonomyName = "group";
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
echo '<ul>';
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug,$taxonomyName).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($term_children as $term_child_id)
    {
        $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a>';
        echo '<ul>';
        $tax_arg = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomyName,
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term_child_id
                )
            )
        );
        $posts = get_posts($tax_arg);
        foreach($posts as $post)
        {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Akshay, you are a genius. Thank you very much for your help.
It turned out that I forgot to mention it was a custom post type, not a post. So your answer worked when I changed this simple argument.

Thanks again!